# How to get notification in website when any changes are made in Google Calendar?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I need to implement a concept in a php website, where I can sync my Google Calendar and later on when ever I make any changes in Google Calendar its changes should reflect to my website's calendar as well.

For that currently I have used Google's [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). With the help of this I am able to connect my Google Calendar but not able to sync the Google calendar with my website when ever any change is made to Google Calendar. Can any one give me suggestions what can be done to achieve this.

I have tried even with the https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push but with the given documentation could not get the notifications.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar doesn't currently do push for web pages, only servers. You'll need to bring a server in the middle and forward the push to the browser when one arrives. I would recommend you look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) and possibly also into alternatives described at the bottom.